# Determine if key press is physical or simulated

Tags: api, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-events

Is it possible to detect if a key was pressed physically or simulated by the Win32 API?

If it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: The question is so clear. Not sure why these guys closed it and accuse it "too broad". If you do not understand an issue, can"t you keep away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to differentiate is to use a low-level keyboard hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx).  When a key is pressed, the [callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) you register will tell you whether or not the event was "injected" (via `keybd_event()` or `SendInput()`).  If the event is not injected then it was generated by the driver of an actual keyboard.